# Oracle Apex 5: retain format of Interactive Report on download

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In Oracle Apex 5, a user can manipulate an Interactive Report's data with a number of actions (Sort, Filter, Group By, Control Break...).  However, when the report is downloaded as a CSV only the Filter action is retained from the manipulations.  How can you get the download of an Interactive Report to display the report as is?

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution I could find is a plugin found on github, see [Interactive Report to Excel v2](http://glebovpavel.github.io/Description_IR_TO_XSLX/)

At the time, it worked for the particular report we had an issue with (Control Break on one column, with some Sorting), but when I tried it on a Group By it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

We have had good results with [APEX_IR_XLSX](https://github.com/commi235/APEX_IR_XLSX/blob/master/ora/apexir_xlsx_pkg.pkb) and have added our own customization pieces to it quite easily.